# Window operations on date column in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am attempting to group data that fits into a specified window period using Spark Structured Streaming.

```
val profiles = rawProfiles.select("*")
    .groupBy(window($"date", "10 minutes", "5 minutes").alias("date"), $"id", $"name")
    .agg(sum("value").alias("value"))
    .join(url.value, Seq("url"), "left")
    .where("value > 20")
    .as[profileRecord]
```

The format of the date from the rawProfiles is a string like this:

> 2017-07-20 18:27:45

What is returned for the date column after the window aggregation is something like this:

> [0,554c749fb8a00,554c76dbed000]

I'm not really sure what to do with that.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: look into casting the date column before you let spark interpret it..

Comment: I tried to cast it to date and that didn't work.  I then tried to use a udf to change it to a date by specifying the format.  Still no luck.  I'm not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 1):

you can reformat your date field as follows;

```
rawProfiles.select(<your other fields>,to_date(unix_timestamp($"date").cast(DataTypes.TimestampType)).as("date"))).groupBy(window($"date", "10 minutes", "5 minutes").alias("date"), $"id", $"name")
.agg(sum("value").alias("value"))
.join(url.value, Seq("url"), "left")
.where("value > 20")
.as[profileRecord]
```